# Excel - Count cells from a specific month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

I'm trying to count the number of cells that are filled in column C for September. In this case, it would be 1.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

I've been trying to use COUNTIF or COUNTIFS but I'm not that expert in excel

Comment: This will work : `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1:A19)=9)*(C1:C19<>""))` Caveat, this will give you the count for the month of `September` for any year. If you want for a specific year then use this : `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1:A19)=9)*(C1:C19<>"")*(YEAR(A1:A19)=2023))` Using `COUNTIFS()` would be like this : `=COUNTIFS(A1:A19,">="&DATE(2023,9,1),A1:A19,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(2023,9,1),0),C1:C19,"<>")`

Comment: Glad to know that, it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment by Mayukh Bhattacharya works like a charm. Here's the solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1:A19)=9)*(C1:C19<>""))
```